# Rails skip passvord filtration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I need to pass params[:password] via post and then create user with devise.
If i do something like:

```
<%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control" %>
```

my params[:password] into controller is nil.

What can i do ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

Your `f.password_field` is inside a `form_for` - this means that in params the value will be in something like `params[:user][:password]` rather than just `params[:password]`. Take a look in the console window where your server is running to see what params are being passed in the request.

Also, Devise provides a built-in controller for handling user registrations so it's possible you don't need to be doing this yourself.